# What is the quickest way to load a serialized hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have serialized a HashMap into a file using objectstream and fileoutputstream. It is a very huge HashMap with around 150 million entries. It takes a long time (~40 mins) to load when I read it back from the file.

I am using a FileOutputStream followed by ObjectOutputStream to serialize the object. Then, I am using the ObjectInputStream and FileInputStream to read the object.

Is there a recommended way to read a serialized HashMap so that it loads quickly from the file?

Comment: Yes, using a database in place of a HashMap. SQLite, Postgres, MySQL offer persistence and queries.

Comment: You could also use `GZIPOutputStream` to compress the data before you serialize it, so the file will be smaller and take less time to write/read: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-serialized-object-into-file/ , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html .

Comment: Why don't you show us how you're doing it? Are you at least using a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: I edited my question mentioning the components that I am using to serialize and deserialize the hashmap.

Comment: Are you just saving the HashMap+contents (as one) or just saving its contents?

Comment: in addition to databases that @Aubin provided, embedded H2 might be an easier drop-in replacement for your hash map

Comment: Has H2 persistence? I believe it's a RAM only SQL database.

Comment: @Aubin: it is a full-featured database, it even has clustering and stuff

Comment: @[Denis Tulskiy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/143585/denis-tulskiy) You're right, [H2 is powerful! Not only in memory](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases)

Answer (score 6):

Using a BufferedInputStream should improve the performance:

```
ObjectInputStream in = 
    new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

And of course, a BufferedOutputStream would also improve the performance of the serialization.

Using those buffered streams allow reading large chunks of bytes from the file system in one shot, instead of reading byte per byte. Read the documentation for more information.

Comment: This improved my load times from 60s to 1.5s (~40x improvement) for a 30MB file.